# Javascript console returning unexepected token else

Tags: javascript

I am using codecademy to learn javascript. I am currently creating a rock paper scissors game and I do not understand why I am getting the error `unexpected token else`
http://pastebin.com/pcCYZecd

Comment: line 14 trailing semicolon

Comment: Please post your code in your question, [not a link to it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428).

Comment: Hmm, do I flag because they left the code out or because it's a typo? Decisions, decisions...

Comment: @j08691 I'm going for typo…

Comment: @S0lo, http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `;`, because the semicolon ends the `if` statement.

Usually there is no need for any semicolon at this place, because you use a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block).

```
if(choice1 === choice2){
    return "The result is a tie!";
}; // remove this semicolon
else if(choice1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a semicolon before your `else`:

```
if(choice1 === choice2){
    return "The result is a tie!";
}; // <-- here
```

Comment: Please vote to close the question as off-topic due to a typo instead of trying to farm rep from it.

Comment: I wasn't trying to "farm rep". I was just answering the question. I wasn't even aware typos were a reason to close a question.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(choice1 === choice2){
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }; <-- remove ;
```